# Numpy summation of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two relatively similar operations I'd like to figure out how to do.

The first is the simpler.  I have a numpy array like

```
[[a,b,c,d],
 [e,f,g,h],
 [i,j,k,l]]
```

I would like to sum the columns to yield:

```
[6,12,18,24]
```

I know that I can do this with a for loop:

```
for i in range(0,ROW_LENGTH): #ROW_LENGTH defined elsewhere
    listsum[i]=list[:,i].sum()
```

But this can't be the pythonic way, can it?

---

The second task is I need to do something similar with a 3D array.  I assume the solution to this will be similar.  A simple example is:

```
[[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]],
 [[j,k,l],[m,n,o],[p,q,r]],
 [[s,t,u],[v,w,x],[y,z,_]]]
```

Where the output should be:

```
[[a+j+s,b+k+t,c+l+u],[d+m+v,e+n+w,f+o+x],[g+p+y,h+q+z,i+r+_]]
```

I'm hopeful that understanding the technique for both of these will be a major boon, generally speaking, for how well I grasp python!

I'm going to link here to a separate question I'm asking for the same project:

Comment: Do you know about the `axis` parameter in `np.sum`? It allows you to perform these operation very efficiently.

Comment: WOW.  Yes.  Exactly.  So what I want is np.sum(list,axis=0), correct?  Can you put this in answer form so I can upvote and select?  This also solves the other problem I was going to link to, which was with a product instead.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad it helped - I've marked this question as a duplicate so it can help direct users to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you can use the [sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) method of numpy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a.sum(axis=0)
```

That should do the trick